# Why does my POST ajax call passes as GET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

After several days of searching here's my question (the issue drives me really mad)

I pass a ajax call with a post method in order to submit a form.
Unfortunately, the `$(form).submit()` does not suit in my case. Here is jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/_MyJson',
    type: 'POST',
    method: "POST",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function (data)              
    {
        // I will add a redirection here later
    }

});
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _MyJson (MyViewModel vm)
{
 //action here
}
```

Route Config:
    `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

The issue is that in Chrome console my call is passed as GET and it gives me 404 error. On the controller side the `_MyJson` method exists and it has a `[HttpPost]` declared.

My jquery version is 2.1.4. I use aspx WebForms and a MVC model.

I am thankful for any help!

UPD: 
After switching to Mozilla debugger, I've found out that my POST call is passing with the statut 301, and there's a GET with the same name which gives a 404 error. O_o

Comment: Do you use route config? if so check your routes to see what it is mapped to.

Comment: type is an alias to method. You don't need both. But this is not what solves your problem.

Comment: `type` parameter is useless. From jQuery documentation: `You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.`

Comment: Please update your question to show the action method you're posting to, as well as the related routing configuration. Also, how do you know that it's coming through as a GET request?

Comment: @mason , it looks like you're right, I'll look if there's a slash missing somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Try using the shorthand:

```
$.post("/Controller/_MyJson", $('#form').serialize(), function (data) {
  // stuff with data
});
```

Comment: Thank you and especially for editing my question, I'm new to formatting. The `$.post` shorthand gives the same result, a GET with 404 error. 
Do you think I can make a `$(form).submit` and if the submit is succesfull, redirect to another page?

Comment: @bugkiller Looks like your post to your POST request, the response is redirecting. Can you preserve the log and see what's happening on the Network tab?

Comment: you're right! the POSt is passing with the 301 Moved Permanently statut, and there's a GET method with the same name which gives 404 error

Comment: @bugkiller Ha ha... So remove the duplicate and I guess you solved it?

Comment: There's no duplicate,it seems that If an AJAX request to a page that receives a "301 Moved Permanently" response, an empty GET request is made to the new location.

Comment: @bugkiller I am not good in ASP.NET AJAX. Now you found out the issue is with this, and not with jQuery or POST. I guess you need to ask a new question now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are serializing the whole Form data. The Controller HttpPost method must match this object otherwise GET method will throw 404 error. Try to create a custom object in the controller and send the appropriate JSON data from the ajax call. This will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you! My controller's method receives a ViewModel which matches the form's model. For example, when I try  '$(form).submit' it works perfectrly. I just can't make out how to redirect to another page after a succesfull  '$(form).submit', that's why I make a plain ajax call